# CAST string as DATETIME

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl, business-intelligence

I have the following query :

```
SELECT '31/12/1999 00:00:00' AS ODSUpdatedate
```

I want to ass a derived column `ODSUpdatedate` like below :

[image]

I am getting this following error :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the expression to :

```
(DT_DATE) "31/12/1999 00:00:00"
```